# Using key in csv to retrieve corresponding multiple keys and their values with dbi

Tags: mysql, perl, csv, dbi

Sorry for the title, don't know a better way of describing it. I am a bit stuck at the moment and could use some help.

I'm trying to retrieve values from a database using DBI. I have a CSV file with keys and multiple corresponding keys in a table with their values.

The CSV looks like this, fairly simple:

```
ID;Etc;Etc
10003999;Data;More Data;
10003800;Data;More Data;
10019764;Data;More Data;
10054483;Data;More Data;
10054540;Data;More Data;
10063434;Data;More Data;
10067815;Data;More Data;
10067819;Data;More Data;
10073005;Data;More Data;
```

The data in the database looks like this:

```
ID          Value
10003999    176
10003999    225
10003999    161
10003999    137
10003800    38
10003800    225
10003800    141
10003800    176
10003800    181
10003800    176
10003800    175
10003800    137
10019764    137
10073005    41
```

As you can see one ID in the csv file can match multiple ID's in the database table.
What I'm after is this:

```
ID;Etc;Etc;;;
10003999;Data;More Data;176;225;161;137
10003800;Data;More Data;175;176;38;176;141;225;137;181
10019764;Data;More Data;137
10054483;Data;More Data;
10054540;Data;More Data;
10063434;Data;More Data;
10067815;Data;More Data;
10067819;Data;More Data;
10073005;Data;More Data;41
```

Because I don't know how many corresponding values the ID has I push them onto the array. It works but it only pushes one value onto the array (where it finds a match), instead of 8 (example id: 10003859). How do i continue? I'm guessing a second loop? because this is beyond me.. This is my script and what I have so far. Its not the best code because this is what I have to work with..i can't adjust it or use modules (except dbi). And to be honest, I'm not good with Perl.

```
# Opening and connecting stuff here

my $sql_query = "SELECT id,value FROM `data`.`table`";
my $hash = $dbh->selectall_hashref($sql_query,'id');

my $i = 0;
my @infile=<INFILE>;

foreach (@infile) {
    my @elements = split(";",$infile[$i]);
    chomp(@elements);
    if (exists $hash->{$elements[$kolom_key]}) {
        my $value = $hash->{$elements[$kolom_key]}->{value};    
        push (@elements, $value);
        undef $value;
    };
    $elements[-1] = $elements[-1] . "\n";
    @elements = join(";",@elements);
    print OUTFILE "@elements"; 
    $i = $i+1;
}

$dbh->disconnect;
close(INFILE);
close(OUTFILE);
```

Comment: You have not assigned any value to `$kolom_key`

Comment: True, its not visible in the script.. I use STDIN to assign a value to $kolom_key (its under "opening and connecting stuff"

Comment: Perhaps you should check the documentation and see what it is that `selectall_hashref` does. Then use `Data::Dumper` and `print Dumper $hash` to see what kind of data structure you actually have. It is almost always preferred to not fetch all data at once, or read a whole file into an array at once, if it is at all possible to avoid. Which it is in this case, and it is possible to make this considerably simpler.

Comment: Does the IDs in the csv file exactly match all of the IDs in the database? I.e. can you iterate over either one and be sure that all of the IDs have been accounted for?

Comment: I have read about data dumper and it looks like a useful module so I want to use it. Will be perfect for telling me what is going on. But for now I am happy if I can get this working. The Id's are exactly the same in the database.. That should be possible but i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $hash;` is rather simple. Then you will know what you are dealing with. Since I am not sure what that data structure looks like, I cannot give advice how to fix it. In Perl, a hash key is unique, and you have IDs with multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

This pair of lines duplicates some work:

```
foreach (@infile) {
    my @elements = split(";",$infile[$i]);
```

The `foreach` puts an array element into `$_` so there is no need to index the array again. The whole use of `INFILE`, `@infile` and the top of the loop can be simplified to

```
while(<>) {
    my @elements = split(";");
```

The line `@elements = join(";",@elements);` looks wrong. The three lines after the loop might be better as

```
print OUTFILE join(";",@elements), "\n";
```

When the obvious improvements are made to the code then any real errors should be easier to identify.

Make sure the `# Opening and connecting stuff here` also includes `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: I know a few thing aren't perfect but I have to work with it like this. I do appreciate your tips though! helps a lot and looking in to it. Yes i'm using stricts and warning :) It runs without errors

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use `selectall_hashref`, [if a row has the same key as an earlier row then it replaces the earlier row.](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.630/DBI.pm#selectall_hashref) Use `selectall_arrayref` or `fetchrow_arrayref` instead:

```
# Slice => {} lets you use column names instead of array indexes
my $results = selectall_arrayref($sql_query, { Slice => {} });

# OR

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_query);
$sth->execute;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) { ... }
```

In general, I would recommend using the `fetchrow_` methods instead of `selectall_` or `fetchall_`, because the latter will read your entire result set into memory (although in this case, we need to build a hash containing the results anyway, so it doesn't really matter).

You will need to build your own hash of IDs to values:

```
my %hash;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) { 
    push @{ $hash{ $row->[0] } }, $row->[1];
}
die $sth->errstr if $sth->err; # If you didn't set RaiseError in DBI::connect
```

Each key in the hash will correspond to an array of values.

I would rewrite the rest of your code something like this:

```
open my $in_fh, "<", "infile" or die $!; # Use lexical file handles
open my $out_fh, ">", "outfile" or die $!;

while (<$in_fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id) = split /;/;

    print;
    print join(";", @{ $hash{$id} }) if exists $hash{$id};
    print "\n";
}

close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pushing only one value because your hash contains only one value.

The first thing is since your table have many values for one key, You should not use selectall_hashref because it overwrites the value if a row has the same key as an earlier row.

Instead use [fetchall_arrayref](http://search.cpan.org/%7Etimb/DBI-1.53/DBI.pm#fetchrow_array). It will give you the an array reference to each row from the output of the select statement.

Note: Now after using fetchall_arrayref it would be difficult for you to search for a particular key as you wont be able to use simple exist method. My suggestion is you change your SQL statement

> Read from a file and iterate over it
>
> use Split to get the KEY_REQ
>
> Make statement "Select key,value from $table where key=KEY_REQ"
>
> Execute the statement
>
> Fetch data using fetchall_arrayref
>
> Push data to the array required